# Trouble adding QStringList items to a QComboBox in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

I'm making an application using Qt and C++ and I'm having trouble with getting addItems() to work with a QComboBox. The following code works fine:

```
QComboBox *subtype = new QComboBox(this);
subtype->addItems({ "itm1", "itm2" });
```

However, putting the QStringList into a variable, as shown here:

```
QComboBox *subtype = new QComboBox(this);
QStringList qsl = { "itm1", "itm2" };
subtype->addItems(qsl);
```

causes an error that says "Function definition for 'addItems' not found."

This behavior seems odd to me. Are variables not allowed in this case, or am I declaring/defining something incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Your code-example looks totally reasonable. Works fine with MingGW and Qt5.9 on Win10.
Also the Qt-libs show the fitting signature for your second addItems(..)-call.
 [image: code and runtime-view]

Comment: I'm using the Qt Visual Studio Tools extension with Qt 5.12.0 in VS 15.8.2. [Here's](https://imgur.com/3avbX4w) an example of the error with the working version above it. I can't figure out how to see what compiler I'm using, but I'm also on Windows 10.